# suppose $(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $[c,d ]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Why can we take$ \lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ but not $ \lim_{x \to c}f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

In the notes I'm working through it says that "to talk about the limit at a point you have to be able to approach the point from both sides. However, for the end points of a closed interval, you can only approach the endpoint(s) from inside the interval"? 
To provide some context, we're comparing the definitions of continuity of a function on a closed interval vs continuity of a function on an open interval.

Comment: Uh.... you can?  Where did you get the idea you can't do $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$?  You most certainly *CAN* do $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$. ....  By the way $\in$ means is an element of; not is a subset of.  And $(a,b)$ and $[c,d]$ are intervals and not individual single real numbers, you want to claim they are subsets of the reals; not that they are themselves real numbers.  You need to use the notation $(a,b)\subset \mathbb R$ and $[c,d]\subset \mathbb R$.  What you wrote would be considered incorrect and unacceptable.

Comment: It's $\subset,$ not $\in.$

Comment: For typical calculus course for beginners, the notion of limit is simplified. And there are notions of left and right hand limit as well. But in a general setting we can talk about $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) $ provided $c$ is a limit point of domain of $f$. Work with the definition of limit given in your prescribed textbook.